# Why stream_get_contents not working with ssh2?

Tags: php, stream, ssh2

I use next code for receiving time of server Debian:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('123.123.123.123', 23452);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'kvn', 'kvn');
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '/bin/date');
$err_stream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
$dio_stream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
stream_set_blocking($err_stream, true);
stream_set_blocking($dio_stream, true);
$result_err = stream_get_contents($err_stream);
$result_dio = stream_get_contents($dio_stream);

echo ($result_dio);
?>
```

But code crashes on string:

> $result_err = stream_get_contents($err_stream)

I tried `fgets()` but code crashes too. Why it this possible? How I can receive string from stream? Thank you!

Comment: What language is this?  This code doesn't *look* like it runs out of the box, and doesn't look like it has a minimum example to 'work'.

Comment: What is the error when it crashes?

Comment: No errors. Connection was reset